# Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13fgN24cwLpVondVd0FDZ5zlXMzbBjgunZMAieuThfVw/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to split a column of data, where there are multiple lines in a single cell. I want these split into rows with a formula.

I've got the JOIN formula set up for that and it works perfectly when I tested with just a few rows. But I have around 200 rows of data and this formula gives me the error `Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.` I get the same error with TEXTJOIN

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(CHAR(10),Data!C2:C),CHAR(10)))
```

Is there anyway I can fix this, to bypass the limit?

I've looked at CONCATENATE too but I need to join cells with a delimiter so I can split later. And query function, I couldn't figure out if its possible with that.

Current format
[image]

Result format

[image]

Basically the multiline cells split into separate rows.
And to further explain my purpose, I don't require all the cells, just only the cells where the value is either paid/pending/not paid, I'll be putting these 3 into separate sheets. I have the formulas for filtering this too, but the block is this **limit of 50000 characters**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465), like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  substitute( 
    transpose( 
      split( 
        query( 
          filter( 
            substitute( substitute(Data!C2:C, " ", "_"), char(10), " " ), 
            (Data!B2:B = "paid") + (Data!B2:B = "not paid")
          ), 
          "", 9^9 
        ), 
        " " 
      ) 
    ), 
    "_", " " 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Doublenary. This works perfectly. I do want to be able to understand the function. What does the 9^9 stand for?

Comment: The `9^9` is simply a big number, about `3.87E+08`. See [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still working on the function trying to figure it our. One more thing, when I changed the  (Data!B2:B = "paid") to something with numbers "250p" I get #N/A - No matches are found in FILTER evaluation. Actually it could contain text after the search term too, such as 250p paid, or 350p pending.

Comment: To do partial text searches in a `filter()`, use `search()` or `regexmatch()` instead of testing for equality. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).